# Reason to go for Akka Clustering

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Coming from server side infra point of view, I find it difficult in understanding the implementation, failover-ability and high-availibility concept of Akka Cluster as opposed to VMware/hyperV ones.

Say I have three nodes, they are all located in different locations but still sitting in the same LAN. In each nodes i have different services(roles) in them. 
Then how does services in Node A will failover to Node B/C if it fails ? Do i need to deploy the same services in Node A to Node B/C as well in prior and let DNS take care of the rest ?